# sqlite protect field name

Tags: sql, sqlite

In MySQL I can use ` in a query to protect a field name, so I can have a field "order" or "group".

I tryed sqlite doc but I cannot find it.
Is it the same quote mark for sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite uses double quotes `"`, like `"field"`.

It is hard to find in the sqlite documentation, the closest I can find is the [FAQ (item 24) about single and double quotes.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24).

Comment: to set MySQL to use them too: SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';

Comment: but watch out if you are using field="value" :)